# The leaves of my chilly plant is drying inspite of water in them daily

Tags: shrubs

I water my plants daily, yet the chilly plat is drying off, all the leaves are almost dead, plz help me, all suggestions accepted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include photographs of the plant in question. Instructions are at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: by "Chilly" do you mean a pepper plant, that bears "chili peppers" ?

Comment: Plants should never be watered daily...with few exceptions.  Seed starts sure, and shallowly.  Chili is a pepper that needs lots of sun, no cold nights and well drained soil.  Is your plant in a pot or is it in the garden?  Where is it that you live?